# Prevent Circle from Flickering in KineticJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, kineticjs

When a user places his mouse cursor over/near the outline of the Polygon, an anchor should appear and follow the position of the mouse, but snapping to the outline of the Polygon.

**Problem:** The anchor seems to flicker when the `mousemove` handler function updates the position of this anchor. What's causing the flickering and the slow update? The KineticJS example [here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-path-mouseover/) appears to update pretty quickly.

Also, the anchor is not snapping to the outline/stroke of the Polygon. How can this effect be achieved?

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yZFFJ/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mousemove` function is moving the anchor.  Once the anchor is moved your mouse is no longer over the `polyHitArea` so your `mouseleave` event is firing and hiding the anchor.

**Edit**

The best way that I can think of off hand to prevent this from happening is to place the `setVisible(false)` code into a `setTimeout` call -- and have a `mouseenter` event on the `mouseoverAnchor` call `clearTimeout`.

```
var polyHitArea._timeout = 0;

polyHitArea.on('mouseover', function(e) {
    clearTiemout(polyHitArea._timeout);
    mouseoverAnchor.setVisible(true);
    stage.draw();
});

polyHitArea.on('mouseleave', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(polyHitArea._timeout);
    polyHitArea._timeout = setTimeout(function(){
        mouseoverAnchor.setVisible(false);
    }, 25); // 25 ms enough time?
    stage.draw();
});

mouseoverAnchor.on('mouseenter', function(e) {
    clearTimeout(polyHitArea._timeout);
});
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Is there a way to prevent the anchor from triggering the `mouseleave` event? I tried `mouseout` and get the same problem.

Comment: Thank Jason. I tried it out and the flickering stops, but the anchor does not follow the mouse position as I move the mouse along the edge of the square. The anchor only updates its position when the mouse exits the anchor, was hoping for an anchor that tracks the mouse position smoothly but constrained to the edge of the square. jsfiddle.net/yZFFJ/8

Comment: Sounds like you are going to need to put your `mousemove` event on the canvas itself and perform all needed calculations there (entering bounds, leaving bounds, whether or not to display the anchor and at what location).